# Were McCoy's medical instruments Swedish salt shakers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, behind-the-scenes, props

A rumour I had heard a long time ago was that Dr. McCoy's small medical devices in *The Original Series* were actually Swedish salt shakers.

[image: Example from the Star Trek photo club]

**Are there any statements corroborating this?**

Comment: http://www.trekbbs.com/threads/props-re-used.81174/page-9#post-2656589

Comment: Now, the real question is whether you could use _any_ kind of salt with these shakers, or did it _have_ to be Swedish salt?

Comment: I would have guessed something more risque than salt shakers.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

## Yes, they were.

The following excerpt from an article quotes **Gene Roddenberry** himself (via the authoritative book ***The Making of Star Trek***) as saying:

> [Feinberg] went out and bought a selection of very exotic-looking salt shakers. It was not until after he brought them in and showed them to me that I realized they were so beautifully shaped and futuristic that the audience would never recognize them as salt shakers. I would either have to use 20th Century salt shakers or I would have to have a character say “See, this is a salt shaker.” So I told Irving to go down to the studio commissary and bring me several of their salt shakers, and as he turned to go, **I said “However, those eight devices you have there will become Dr. McCoy’s operating instruments.” For two years now, the majority of McCoy’s instruments in Sick Bay have been a selection of exotic salt shakers**, and we know they work, because we’ve seen them work. Not only has he saved many a life with them but it’s helped keep our prop budget costs low...

([Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160814194150/http://spinoff.comicbookresources.com/2013/05/15/tv-legends-revealed-were-mccoys-star-trek-instruments-salt-shakers/))

The author of the article, having done more research, concludes that Roddenberry's recollection was "slightly off" and that exactly two of the instruments were salt shakers while the rest were constructed by the prop team to resemble those two.

Finally, **William Shatner** himself mentions that the salt shakers were of Swedish origin in his 2002 book ***Star Trek: I'm Working on That***:

> ...or how Bones was supposed to perform medical magic by waving weird gadgets (**Swedish salt shakers actually**) over damaged bodies.

([Source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pCUtTlIFLZQC&pg=PP4&lpg=PP4&dq=star+trek+i%27m+working+on+that&source=bl&ots=0r3QbxUrbW&sig=ZUEmC37Xlgy9NqFclBagGdFmShw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp3928-9fNAhXGz4MKHR6GCz8Q6AEITjAO#v=onepage&q=Swedish&f=false))

Comment: You asked and answered your own question?

Comment: @iMerchant : Indeed.  It's explicitly encouraged by StackExchange.  When you're posting a question, you have the option to answer your question at the same time.  The rationale is that, if you had a question that you now have an answer for, then you should share your newfound knowledge instead of not posting at all.  :-)

Comment: Also referenced in Shatner's *Star Trek: Memories* with essentially the same story of repurposed prop salt shakers.

Comment: +1 for very well researched and fascinating self Q/A

Comment: @Praxis, sometimes. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9919/is-it-possible-to-ask-for-moderators-to-check-if-a-user-has-abnormally-downvoted#comment28424_9919  But, personally that was a great find, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Praxis: I'd say answering your own question is appropriate when you've done research since you asked your question and are coming back - *at a later time* to report your findings. You seem to have answered your question at about the same time you answered it, making it more of a blog post than a question-and-answer. I'm not sure that should really be appropriate.

Comment: @einpoklum Take it up with the entirety of Stack Exchange. It's a completely accepted practice. Hell, when you're posting a question, there's a "I'm going to self-answer this" checkbox. It adds knowledge to the network, what's the problem?

Comment: @einpoklum From [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), "it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site. To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is *explicitly encouraged***".

Comment: Plus it's a great way to get yourself a bunch of reputation points.....

Comment: @L0j1k Only if you write a good question and a good answer.

Comment: @Oriol: Just don't complain when I ask and answer "How much wood would a wood chuck chuck, if a wood chuck could chuck wood?"

Comment: This is a fine out-of-universe answer, but it's not clear from the question whether the OP is asking if the medical instruments were Swedish salt shakers in universe or out of universe.

Comment: @Praxis - Thanks to all these comments for clearing this up. I've seen self-answered questions that were downvoted because they were self-answered before. So I was confused.

Answer (score -2):

The Swedish salt shakers used – from what I've seen online – had orange and green wooden lower bodies and conical metal upper parts.
[image: Swedish Salt Shakers]

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is indeed what was used in the show? Could you [edit] it in if you do?